# getting this erro while creating react app

Tags: reactjs

[exactly this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZrIp.png)

npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno EIO
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/saxes: EIO: i/o error, read

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\kd_Prakash\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-07T01_57_58_958Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 0):

`create-react-app` is now deprecated and they no longer updating it. so it you want to use latest and updated react then use vite for installing react

check Documentation  :
https://vitejs.dev/guide/

Command For create react app :

For Javascript : `npm create vite@latest my-vue-app --template react`

For Typescript : `npm create vite@latest my-vue-app --template react-ts`

check for Why don't use create-react-app
https://dev.to/ag2byte/create-react-app-is-officially-dead-h7o

Thank you